# Dropdown list of class in form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a web application with Entity Framework and have some problem that I'm not sure how to solve. It's in the `Create.cshtml` file with autogenerated form content. From the beginning I had an enum of countries in a dropdown list and then I had to change to a class beacuse I also needed to be able to add or delete contries in the list. But then the alternative below don't work and I have tried to use `DropDownList` and `DropDownListFor` but without any progress! What am I doing wrong?

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This is the model for the dropdown list:

```
    public class CountryNames
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: An updated class(Not sure I have done it the right way!?)

```
    public class CountryNames
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCountryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }

    //public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: Create Action Method in Controller

```
// GET: Persons/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var countryNames = new CountryNames();

        countryNames.Countries = CountriesList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() });

        return View(countryNames);

        //return View();
    }
```

Comment: Please specify what does not work.

Answer (score 1):

So in your controller you would have something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var vm = new SomeViewModel();

    vm.Countries = CountriesList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() });

    return View(vm);
}

public class SomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries {get;set;}

    public int SelectedCountryId {get;set;}
}
```

The CSHTML:

```
@model some.namespace.path.SomeViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCountryId, Model.Countries, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

So to summarise, you have the view model acting as a container for objects to be displayed on the view (cshtml). A list of Countries which are `SelectListItem` because that is what `DropDownList` understands.

In the controller you have that `Select` operating on the `CountriesList` which is taking all the `CountryNames` objects and turning them into `SelectListItem`s.

Finally there is a property on the ViewModel called `SelectedCountryId` which is set by the drop down list when you select a particular country.

FYI:

`CountriesList` is a variable that is some form of an `IEnumerable<CountryNames>` it can be retrieved from a database or a static class which contains the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added your code inside the Create action method. I get a red line below the Select! The error message is something about object does not contain a definition for SELECT. In your code you use this: return View(vm); But what about the rest of the forms content? Will that also return to the View?

Comment: You will have to put your code for your create action on your question so that I can see it. Then I will be able to give you help from there. The view model is there for all the form content as well, so put any form properties on it!

Comment: Yeah so, your view model you have called `CountryNames` you also have another class called `CountryNames`, I suggest you change your view model to be called `CreateViewModel`. And your `CountriesList` needs to be of type `IEnumerable<CountryNames>` and be populated from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use ViewBag instead:

your Controller should be

public ActionResult GetCountries()
    {
        ViewBag.Countries= EntitiesObject.CountriesTable.Select(x => x.Countries).ToList();
        return View();
    }

View:
@model xyz.Models.exampleModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries), "-- Choose your country --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

In Class/Model

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Country{ get; set; }
    }
```